# JWT Bearer token not received?

Tags: spring-security, jwt

I want to use Spring security to perform authentication and authorization on 2 separated server.

I've authenticated successfully and received a JWT token on the first server.

Now I am sending a request to the second server with the JWT authorization token, but the server can't see it; basically `getHeader()` from `getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request)` returns null.

This is the server code:

```
//imports...

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

```
//imports...

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);
            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                Long userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
// bearerToken prints null!
        System.out.println("AUTHORIZATION: "+bearerToken);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the token is present on the request:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorization header was stripped on the edge server